# 301 Redirect Dynamic to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

i want to redirect (301) my (old) URLs/Links with mod_rewrite. But i don´t know the rules i have to use in the htaccess.

My URL is one like this

https://www.pausenhof.de/referat/physik/magnetismus/14619

and now i want to move it to

https://www.pausenhof.de/referat/physik-magnetismus-14619

how is the **301** rule for redirect for google?

this here are dynmaic
https://www.pausenhof.de/referat/**physik**/**magnetismus**/**14619**

many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

i have found it. this rule work

RewriteRule ^referat/([a-zA-Z0-9.*+-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9.*+-]+)/([0-9]+)$ referat/$1-$2-$3 [L,R=301]